# Как сделать ЧПУ, для ListView paginate_by

Tags: python, django

Приветствую. Работаю с django 1.5. Ссылки для paginate (CBV) выводятся как параметр ?page=2. Подскажите, что нужно сделать для того, чтобы вид ссылок был /page/2?

Вот urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from stories import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^story/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

)

И кусок views.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'stories/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'stories'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Story.objects.order_by('-pub_date')

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'title'
        return context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вьюхи есть метод paginate_queryset (кстати, советую в таких случаях читать исходники - там все довольно понятно).

Но реально объект (на который должна указывать основная часть URL) у Вас - список, а номер страницы и прочие фильтры - параметры отображения этого объекта. Я бы оставил as is, Ваш вариант не "человекопонятнее", а даже наоборот - навскидку непонятно, как мне модифицировать URL, если я хочу попасть на первую страницу или сбросить фильтры.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение :)